# How to plot the frequency response of transconductance of BJT with LTSpice

Tags: bjt, ltspice

I need to plot the frequency response of the transconductance of this circuit in the picture with LTSpice but I don't know how. Can you please help me urgently how should I do it?
Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential gain of your circuit is directly proportional to the overall transconductance. Therefore - if you know the gain formula of the circuit it should be possible to extract the transconductance by a simple mathematical division process. Because there are no external capacitors in the circuit, you can derive the frequency dependence of the transconductance from a simulation in the frequency domain (ac analysis). Question: Do the transistor models contain a kind of frequency dependence (because all other parts are ideal)?

Comment: Based on the picture of the circuit that I added now, transconductance can be calculated by $${G_m}=\frac{i_o1}{V_i}$$
I think there is no other freq dependent element (just the internal capacitors?!)... 
To achieve $${i_o1}$$ I used $${Ic_1}-{Ic_2}$$. is it correct?

Comment: @ LvW the hardest part is finding the bandwidth of Gm... Can you please help me?

Comment: Did you already simulate the frequency response?